# How do I make part of a regex match optional?

Tags: regex

This is an example string:

```
123456#p654321
```

Currently, I am using this match to capture `123456` and `654321` in to two different groups:

```
([0-9].*)#p([0-9].*)
```

But on occasions, the `#p654321` part of the string will not be there, so I will only want to capture the first group. I tried to make the second group "optional" by appending `?` to it, which works, but only as long as there is a `#p` at the end of the remaining string.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have the `#p` outside of the capturing group, which makes it a required piece of the result. You are also using the dot character (`.`) improperly. Dot (in most reg-ex variants) will match any character. Change it to:

```
([0-9]*)(?:#p([0-9]*))?
```

The `(?:)` syntax is how you get a non-capturing group. We then capture just the digits that you're interested in. Finally, we make the whole thing optional.

Also, most reg-ex variants have a `\d` character class for digits. So you could simplify even further:

```
(\d*)(?:#p(\d*))?
```

As another person has pointed out, the `*` operator could potentially match *zero* digits. To prevent this, use the `+` operator instead:

```
(\d+)(?:#p(\d+))?
```

Comment: I tried that previously, and it works however if there is a second part to the string then the first group is the whole string, and nothing is in the second group.

Comment: The dot in your reg-ex is causing your problem. See my revision.

Comment: And now the second group is `#p654321`. It's visible that it's a part of the group match.

Comment: Ah, so you just want the digits? I misunderstood your goal.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that a capture group after the optional group will keep its reference even if the optional group is not there (as in `\2` will be empty and a fictional third capture group would still be referenced as `\3`, not as `\2`). Just if anybody wonders.

Answer (score 7):

Your regex will actually match *no* digits, because you've used `*` instead of `+`.
This is what  (I think) you want:

```
(\d+)(?:#p(\d+))?
```

Comment: You are correct; the `+` would be a better operator to use. I thought about making that change, but the OP didn't specify whether or not no-digit scenarios were a possibility. As such, I tried to keep it as close to his original as possible.