# Regex that matches 5'2", 6', and 2'-4", but not 3'' (two apostrophes)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse length quantities that use Imperial shorthand notation (`'` for feet, `"` for inches), and I'm in a bit of a quandary. Using this regular expression:

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[ -]\d+\/\d+)?(?:\')/g
```

I can match the following strings (each passed separately within a larger string):

- `5'6"` (matches `5'`)
- `6'`
- `3 1/2'`
- `12.5'`

However, I've run across strings where `''` is used in place of `"`. I tried adding `[^\']` at the end, but that would match `5'6` in the first example, and if I put `[^\'\d]`, it wouldn't match the first example at all. Any help?

Comment: If nothing else works, do a preprocessing step removing all double `''`. Negative lookahead might work, though.

Comment: Try a lookahead: [`\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[ -]\d+\/\d+)?'(?!')`](https://regex101.com/r/dV6xW8/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew put that as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match `5'` in `5'6''`, you just need to use a negative lookahead:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[ -]\d+\/\d+)?'(?!')/g
                                ^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV6xW8/1)

The `(?!')` will fail the whole match if a `'` at the end is followed with another single apostrophe.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz It does not have to. The pattern is not meant to match any double quotes. You need a different pattern, like `\d+'\d+"`. If the `\d+"` part is optional, just wrap it with a non-capturing group and quantify it with `?`: ``\d+'(?:\d+")?``, see [How do I make part of a regex match optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451731).