# Optional nested captching group

Tags: regex

Given the following input:

```
Invoice Date: {InvoiceDate(dd.mm.YYYY)}
Inoice Number: {InvoiceNumber}
```

I am trying to extract

- Match 1:

  1. InvoiceDate
  2. dd.mm.YYYY
- Match 2:

  1. InvoiceNumber

I got [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/YeFifd/1) working for the invoice Date:

```
\{([^}]+)\(([^)]+)\)\}
```

> [image: First regex result]

But obiously, `(dd.mm.YYYY)` is not optional.

Then I tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/BZwkj6/1):

```
\{([^}]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\}
```

Using [`(?:)?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451749/2441442) syntax seems to ignore my inner captching group (dd.mm.YYYY)

> [image: Second Regex result]

So how can I make `\(([^)]+)\)` optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the first capture group lazy:

```
\{([^}]+?)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\}
        ^
```

See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/BZwkj6/1).

Or, restrict the characters in the first capture group with `^(` so it only matches up to the parenthesis:

```
\{([^(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\}
     ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accept as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work typing from scratch, then I had to compare side by side to see what the difference was in our answers:

```
/\{([^}(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\}/ // my answer
/\{([^}]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\}/  // your answer
```

You can see that I specified your first capture group to not include open round bracket. Yours would have been capturing the whole string `Invoicedate(dd.mm.YYYY)` in the first group, leaving nothing for the second.

Here's the [link](https://regex101.com/r/LA9goY/1).

Answer (score 0):

Why not grab each thing separately?

`invoice date: {(.*?)\((.*?)\)}.*?invoice number: {(.*?)}`

- Flags: g, i, s
- Steps: 348

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXmrZw/1)