# Simple regex match numbers with or without hyphen

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the the numbers, where some could be with or without a hyphen "-"

example one: `1: 3`

example two: `24: 9-7`

I tried the following:

```
(\d+): ((\d+)-(\d+)|(\d+))
```

and replace with:

```
A=\1\nB=\2\nC=\3\n
```

It works well for the first example, but not for the one with the hyphen.  It gives the output:

```
A=24
B=9-7
C=9
```

Where it should be:

```
A=24
B=9
C=7
```

---

When I tried this:

```
(\d+): (?:(\d+)-(\d+)|(\d+))
```

the second one was OK, but not the first.

Comment: You need `(\d+): (\d+)(?:-(\d+))?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNDSwI/1))

Comment: It worked.. Thanks! Do I close the question? Or you'd add the answer with an explanation to accept it?

Comment: I agree. This is a suitable dup target [How do I make part of a regex match optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451731/how-do-i-make-part-of-a-regex-match-optional)